# Smoke missing from jpg output

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I have a model (v2.69) that renders smoke in the viewport. However while the model appears in the jpg output the smoke does not.  Every thing is in the same blender layer.  I have recently re-built the machine to Ubuntu 14.04 and the problem persists.  6mths ago it was fine, the hardware has not changed and the example files are in http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338435-Where-can-I-get-some-advice

GIMP works fine, the machine works fine and so this is looking like a Blender setting and something that is stopping the smoke from getting to the output file.

Stuart

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Blender! Could you please add more detail or a .blend file so we can help you.

Comment: I doubt it's a hardware/driver/os issue, as rendering is done on the CPU (I assume you are using BI, if not, then cycles volumetrics are not available on the GPU or CPU in 2.69). More likely something happened in the upgrade (2.69 didn't exist two months ago, so I'm assuming you upgraded).  As GiantCowFilms already said, a blend would be helpful :)

Comment: I've just uploaded test.blend to pasteall.org and cant see a link to send?

Comment: @user4953 Just copy the url from the top of your browser and post it here.

Comment: Link: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30217 to the blend file.